# "mrt add magnific-popup" failing in Meteor

Tags: meteor, meteorite, magnific-popup, atmosphere

I am trying to add Magnific Popup to my meteor project.  When I do mrt add magnific-popup I get the following error:

> ERROR: 1 Command failed: error: pathspec 'v0.9.11+170e942' did not match any file(s) known to git.
>
> STDOUT:
>
> STDERR: error: pathspec 'v0.9.11+170e942' did not match any file(s) known to git.
>
> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/meteorite/lib/sources/git.js:181
>               self.checkoutType + ": " + (self.commit || self.head);
>                                        ^
>   There was a problem checking out tag: v0.9.11+170e942

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a bug with floating point numbers. Change your smart.json and add the stuff inside the brackets in

```
magnific_popup: {
    "git": "https://github.com/Konecty/meteor-magnific-popup.git"
}
```

Then run `mrt update`, and you may also have to run `meteor add magnific_popup` to add it to your `.meteor/packages` file